# Unpivoting columns taken from another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have more then 500 columns that i need to use in unpivoting.

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from ( select * from table )
unpivot (col3 for col2 in ('value', 'value2',....'value788'))
```

So instead of writing all these columns i used inner select of the table that holds all those values.

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from ( select * from table )
unpivot (col3 for col2 in (select value_col from val_table))
but it is throwing error. unexpected select
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a subquery in the <column_list> of the unpivot function. From the documentation:

> The column_list should contain only literal column names, not a subquery.

You would need to write a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html) to do this. The stored proc could take an SQL statement in as a parameter, execute it, and turn the results into a new `unpivot` SQL statement using javascript.

Comment: thx @Simon Darr , i will try to implement it and come back.

Answer (score 1):

This has come up a few times so I thought about a JavaScript stored procedure. However, the labor intensive part is building out and changing the values in the `in` clause. For that, a simple SQL generator works well. Here's an example using the nation table in Snowflake sample data:

```
use schema "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1";

select  '(' || listagg('\'' || N_NAME || '\'', ',') || ')'
from    NATION
```